# Tell if running AOSP or Google Android?

Tags: android

I've searched and cannot find this, though mainly a challenge of knowing what to search for, I'm sure it's been asked before.

How does an app deduce whether it is running on a "Google Android" device, or an AOSP device (e.g. Kindle Fire etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to enumerate an existing accounts on device using `AccountManager` class: [getAccountsByType()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#getAccountsByType%28java.lang.String%29), passing `com.google` as desired account type. If there is no accounts of this type, this mean either it is AOSP device or the user didn't create Google account yet.

If it is not enough for you, you can use `PackageManager` class and query some Google-specific package using [getPackageInfo()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getPackageInfo%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) method. For example, `com.android.vending` - Google Play app.

But pay attention that no one of these methods can guaranty you that target device is running AOSP.

Answer (score 0):

This is not trivial, but most apps do not need to even care. If you do, then it usually means you need some unique features therefore it's simpler to check if certain feature is present or not, instead of what label is on the device. You may also check for presence of certain packages (like Google Play), but lack of it does not mean automatically it is i.e. Fire.

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether you can open market urls by using an Intent.

Documentation on the intent's extras is [here](https://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/promote/linking.html).

The Intent would look like this:

```
try {
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
  intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.example.android"));
  //you can use any package identifier for the check.
  startActivity(intent);
} catch (ActvitiyNotFoundException anfe) {
  //There's no market installed.
  //So you can guess that you're not on a device with Google experience
}
```

The downside of this method would be, that the user will be taken to the Play Store if it's available.